# UglifyJsPlugin still Have problem with es6 using babel-preset-env in Webpack 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, uglifyjs, webpack-4

I'm using the **new version of Ecma Script preset** in Webpack **4** but It still throws the error.

(currently, my bundle.js file size is about 5MB and it's so huge. In addition to UglifyJs, please let me know any other advice to decrease bundle size in **Webpack 4 and ReactJs** if you know)

Here is the error:

```
ERROR in bundle.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: keyword (const) [bundle.js:4981,0]
```

and here is my Webpack config:

```
{

...
...

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'env', 'stage-3'],
                    compact: false
                },
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=./fonts/[name].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=./images/[name].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                include: [
                    resolve(__dirname, "not_exist_path")
                ],
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
            },

        ]
    },

...
...

    optimization: {
        minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin()]
    },
}
```

What am I doing wrong? where is the problem?

Comment: Are you planning on shipping `es6` code?

Comment: no, Is it doesn't come with babel-loader in rules?!

Comment: In webpack 4, Uglify is built-in. You can remove the minimizer option at the end and add [mode: 'production'](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/) instead, see if that fixes the issue